# Phonegap fundamentals

Tags: cordova, phonegap-build

1) If I build via CLI, do I also have only 1 free private app?

2) If I build via CLI, will everything I build be uploaded somewhere?

3) Is there any possibility to build an app and upload it on my server and distribute it via a link?

4)
https://build.phonegap.com/

This site mentions that i can share my app via a link. How does this work, do I have to upload it somewhere?

My goal is to not have to upload it on the os-stores like google-store, cause my app is only for private customers.

Answer (score 0):

1. No. You have as many as you want.
2. No, unless you want it to be. It's not part of the CLI build process though.
3. Yes.
4. PhoneGap Build is a cloud service. If you use it you have the option to share a link with other people so they can download your app.

Comment: Danoram wrote "The PhoneGap Build API allows applications to use the PhoneGap Build web service to create, build, update, and download PhoneGap apps. It integrates easily into IDEs, shell scripts, app builders, and elsewhere." 
and you wrote "No, unless you want it to be. It's not part of the CLI build process though."
now I'm confused. I do not want my code be uploaded somewhere. If I use normal build command in cli, will it be uploaded somewhere?

Comment: It's very simple. Phone Gap Build is a cloud based system - you upload your package and you download a working .apk or .ipa file. You don't have to share this with anyone, but you can if you want. With Phonegap CLI you build the .apk or .ipa on your machine.

Answer (score 0):

- *If I build via CLI, do I also have only 1 free private app?*

If you build via CLI, you wouldn't be using their service so your question isn't really applicable.

From their Documentaion:

> Public apps have their source code hosted in a publicly accessible GitHub repository. Private apps have their source code hosted in a private (non-publicly accessible) GitHub repository or are created when a developer uploads a ZIP file containing the source code and assets to the PhoneGap Build service.

If I am to interpret your question correctly, uploading your source code from CLI development would be the equivalent of creating a public or private app. Which I am guessing you configure using their service from a web portal.

- *If I build via CLI, will everything I build be uploaded somewhere?*

You might want to look into their Developer API if you want to integrate their build service with your local machine:

> The PhoneGap Build API allows applications to use the PhoneGap Build web service to create, build, update, and download PhoneGap apps. It integrates easily into IDEs, shell scripts, app builders, and elsewhere.

To answer your question, unless you use their API, no. Your builds would not be uploaded somewhere because your machine and their service are independent of each other.

- *Is there any possibility to build an app and upload it on my server and distribute it via a link?*

> **What do I do with my app when I get it back from PhoneGap Build? Is it ready for app store submission?**
>
> It depends on the platform that you're targeting. For Android, iOS and Windows Phone 8, you'll need to provide the correct certificates and/or signing keys to allow distribution. See our other documentation for more details on this process.

You will be able to download the ios .ipa or android .apk files from PhoneGap Build so yes, you would be able to distribute your app through a link. Although you might have to provide instructions for your clients on how to do so.

- *This site mentions that i can share my app via a link. How does this work, do I have to upload it somewhere?*

Similar to the last question you would upload your app to PhoneGap Build, you would also provide the required signing certificates, which for iOS you can do through XCode or [Ituness Connect](https://itunesconnect.apple.com/itc/static/login?appIdKey=e0b80c3bf78523bfe80974d320935bfa30add02e1bff88ec2166c6bd5a706c42&view=1&path=%2FWebObjects%2FiTunesConnect.woa%3F) (I think you can?). Not sure how you do it for Android as I have never distributed an Android app.

You then can download the zipped build files for distribution.